# Workbook.close Cannot run the marco "https://wfp-mysharepoint.com............"

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

Background infromation:
This workbook is on shared point and I'm trying to run a Marco in Desktop app.

The objective on the marco is to close the workbook automatically after 10 mins. I want to ensure that users do not keep the workbook open without using it.

However, when I run the below code, I get an error message

> "Cannot run the marco "https://wfp-mysharepoint.com............" This Macro may not be available in this workbook or marcos maybe disabled.

The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Picktime
End Sub

Sub Picktime()
    savetime = Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) + 1 & ":" & Second(Now)
    Application.OnTime savetime, "Please_close"
End Sub

Sub Please_close()
    ThisWorkbook.Close (True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `Please_close` located? If it is in `ThisWorkbook` where also `Workbook_Open` then move `Please_close` into a normal `module`.

Comment: Thank you so much! that did solve the problem! If you have time, would you please explain to my why there is difference

Comment: See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure `Workbook_Open` is an event (that runs automatically) on opening of the workbook and therefore has to be in the scope of the workbook `ThisWorkbook`. Other events that are worksheet related are located in the scope of their worksheet.

All other code should go into a normal module. Especially code that needs to be found by `Application.OnTime` can only be located in a normal module.

So in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Picktime
End Sub
```

In a normal module:

```
Public Sub Picktime()
    Dim SaveTime As Variant
    SaveTime = Now() + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=SaveTime, Procedure:="Please_close"
End Sub

Public Sub Please_close()
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Note that it is easer to add one minute to `Now()` by using `Now() + TimeValue("00:01:00")`